# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText') at HTMLButtonElement.addToCartClicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add some items to the cart, but i am getting this error. What am i doing wrong?

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {   
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
  var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
  addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) updateCartTotal()
}
```

Comment: means you did not find the element. You can not read the innerText if you do not have an element. If you show your HTML, we might be able to help.

Comment: You probably don't have enough `.parentElement`. It will be simpler if you use `.closest(".classname")` where that's the class of the container that includes both the button and the shop item data.